Unable to clone the repo from Github in source tree in Mac OS
I am trying to clone repo from github into my system (Mac os) using sourcetree, But, It is starting the cloing, But in ending time its throwing error like below.
Cloning into '/Users/name/Documents/appname'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 2945 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I have tried change networks, Also tried some following git commands as few forums said.
$ git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000

But nothing works for me. I am trying to clone using Sourcetree tool and trying to cloning the repo into my system documents folder.
Could anyone suggest why it is happening.

Its really strange, I have asked very genuine query here, I really wonder why some people putting it downvote, Really wondering, Instead of downvote, they could have said what is wrong in this query

Probably not the answer you want.
But in my experience, I had a lot of problems when it comes to big packages and GUI like Sourcetree to use Git, even more when there is problem with connections.In these cases, I turn in to the command line.
git clone ssh/url

In the root folder, where you want your git repo
this case
/Users/name/Documents/

There is some necessary setting to run this, but in the long term, is necessary to learn to use git without a GUI
Good luck

I am using sourcetree tool to clone the repo, And I am trying to cloning the repo into my documents folder, But it works for few people with sourcetree

Anyway thank you so much for your quick reply.
